# Google AppEngine only deploys first version

Tags: google-app-engine

I just changed my app.yaml to a new version number before deploying to AppEngine. Everything appeared to be working fine, but when I visit the website on appspot.com it still shows the old version, and https://appengine.google.com/ shows that version 1 is still the live version. What do I do to make it deploy my new version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the default version in the application's Dashboard.

To see a non-default version the URL is `http://<version>.latest.<appname>.appspot.com/`.

Also, you can (and probably should) use text names for version labels instead of numbers.

Comment: Does this not work for apps that are configured to require https (secure: always) ?

Comment: Well, you could change your client app for testing those new versions so it does not validate certificate errors, but using this URL is also no problem if you test it in the browser (either a web page or the API via some REST client addon for example) and accept the certificate warning for the session in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the version in your deployment descriptor (app.yaml) only uploads this new version, it does not set it as the default version. You set the default version in your Dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your dashboard and make that particular version your default version. Feed the  in this url to go to your dashboard: https://appengine.google.com/dashboard?&app_id=s~